# can we create CNAME and subdomain with same name?

Tags: subdomain, cname-record

I need to create CNAME alias for link redirection, and need to create sub-domain for creating email.

Comment: Please elaborate.

Comment: I cannot create a subdomain which already created in CNAME. please help me, if there any way to get same name of both CNAME & subdomain

Comment: Still not clear.  Update your question with what exactly you need (providing either the real CNAME/subdomain names or examples) and explain how you intend on using both.

Comment: test.mydomain.com for my application redirection.

and task@test.mydomain.com for email

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You cannot create `CNAME` and `MX` records for the same name. A `CNAME` cannot co-exist with any other record for the same name.

But when you say that you need a `CNAME` for HTTP redirects, then you are mistaken. A `CNAME` may be convenient, but HTTP doesn't care whether a domain name was resolved using a `CNAME` or not.

So what you can do instead is to create three separate records. One `MX` record, one `AAAA` record, and one `A` record. Records of those three types can co-exist on the same name.